# Replace a window of size n (above, below) of each 1 in pandas column with 1

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have trouble in replacing values above and below of a non-zero number (binary column) with 1.

I looked online SO posts, but was not able to find a way to tackle this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'fullwindow' : [2, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 3, np.NaN, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 5], \
  'up' : [1, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 2,np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2], \
  'down' :[0, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2]})

print data[['up', 'down', 'fullwindow']]
      up  down  fullwindow
 0   1.0   0.0         2.0
 1   NaN   NaN         NaN
 2   NaN   NaN         NaN
 3   NaN   NaN         NaN
 4   1.0   1.0         3.0
 5   NaN   NaN         NaN
 6   2.0   1.0         4.0
 7   NaN   NaN         NaN
 8   NaN   NaN         NaN
 9   NaN   NaN         NaN
 10  NaN   NaN         NaN
 11  2.0   2.0         5.0

dummy = pd.get_dummies(data.fullwindow)
print dummy
    2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
0     1    0    0    0
1     0    0    0    0
2     0    0    0    0
3     0    0    0    0
4     0    1    0    0
5     0    0    0    0
6     0    0    1    0
7     0    0    0    0
8     0    0    0    0
9     0    0    0    0
10    0    0    0    0  
11    0    0    0    1
```

In the dummy dataset columns, values above or below 1 will be replaced by 1. For the first column row 0, (2.0), the fullwindow value is 2, 'up' and 'down' values are 1, and 1.  So, below row (row index 1) for column 2.0 will change from 0 to 1.  There is no above row, so it is left as such.  If there are two overlapping ranges, then it is still 1.   For column 4.0, row index 6 is 1.  It has 2 up and 1 down.  So, row index 4, 5, 7 is changed to 1

The expected output for the example

```
    2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
0     1    0    0    0
1     0    0    0    0
2     0    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0
4     0    1    1    0
5     0    1    1    0
6     0    0    1    0
7     0    0    1    0
8     0    0    0    0
9     0    0    0    1
10    0    0    0    1  
11    0    0    0    1
```

For 5.0, row index 11 is 1.  and up is 2, resulting in 9, 10 rows changed to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a nice question , I am so excited :-), I using `dropna` , then `repeat` and `reindex` , The adjust with `cumcount` in `index` is the key

```
#df=data
sub=df.dropna()#drop na 
subup=sub.reindex(sub.index.repeat((sub.up).astype(int)))
subup.index=subup.index-subup.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)-1
subdown=sub.reindex(sub.index.repeat((sub.down).astype(int)))
subdown.index=subdown.index+subdown.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1
pd.concat([subup,subdown,sub])['fullwindow'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reindex(df.index,fill_value=0)
Out[151]: 
    2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
0     1    0    0    0
1     0    0    0    0
2     0    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0
4     0    1    1    0
5     0    1    1    0
6     0    0    1    0
7     0    0    1    0
8     0    0    0    0
9     0    0    0    1
10    0    0    0    1
11    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Great answer.  Do you think the value in 4.0 for row index 4 be 1.  It is 2 up, 1 down  + value already 1 in row index 6

Comment: The down window index is the issue.  if you check 3.0 or 4.0, row index 5 in 3.0 would also be 1

Comment: @user11337195 let me fix for you

Comment: I tried fixing by `sub = sub.reindex(sub.index.repeat((sub.up + sub.down + 1).astype(int)))` but it throws error in the later steps for duplicate rows

Comment: @user11337195 check the update , this time should match what you need

Comment: This is a great answer.  I was trying with nested for loops.  Couldn't figure out this way.

Comment: I accepted the answer.  Was testing it, sorry.  and was trying to understand the full process